Ward identity and reason why it must hold
I am self-studying QFT using book "Quantum filed theory and the standard model" by M.Schwartz, and I am struggling to understand the chapter 8.4 "Quantization and Ward Identity"
There are even some sentences that I can't understand or frankly they appear to be wrong to me.
At page 125 he states "The group that fixes $p^\mu = (E,0,0,p_z)$ is also $SO(3)$ although it is harder to see"
As far as I know (see as an example Wu-Ki Tung "Group theory in physics" pag. 193) $SO(3)$ fixes $p^\mu = (E,0,0,0)$, but it doesn't fix $p^\mu = (E,0,0,p_z)$ when $p_z \neq 0$. Also from algebraic point of view it can't fix it cause $J_i$ (generators of $SO(3)$) and $P_j$ don't commute if $i \neq j$
At page 126 he states: "Even though there is an irreducible unitary representation of massless spin-1 particles involving two polarizations, it's impossible to embed these polarizations in vector field like $\epsilon_\mu$"
Does that mean the two $\epsilon_\mu$ reported on page 126:
$$
\epsilon_1^\mu(p) = (0,1,0,0), \epsilon_2^\mu(p) = (0,0,1,0)
$$
don't belong to  an irreducible unitary representation of massless spin-1 particles?
As far as I know they don't provide an irreducible unitary representation of massless spin-1 particles, cause we know from Wigner theorem that irreducible unitary representation of Poincare' group are infinity-dimensional, while they are not (cause they are fixed and don't depend on $p$).
Still on page 126 it shows that $ISO(2)$, which we know is the little-group of $p^\mu = (E,0,0,E)$ for massless particles, when acting on the two $\epsilon_\mu$, mixes them with $p_\mu$.
This seems to confirm that the two $\epsilon_\mu$ above don't belong to the space generated by the action of the little-group ISO(2) on $p^\mu = (E,0,0,E)$, so then they can't be used in the induced representations method to generate an irreducible unitary representation.
So to summarize I can't understand how he uses the arguments of little-group and induced representations method to shows that Ward identity must hold to have an $S$ matrix that is invariant under Lorentz transformation.

(8.68,9) and line following them. The space of the three $\epsilon$s with i= 1,2,L are orthogonal and leave p unaffected.

@CosmasZachos I don't get how he can say that $SO(3)$ mixes only the $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_L$ leaving $\epsilon_S$ fixed.

Have you found the two boosts that mix these three, leaving $\epsilon_S\propto P $fixed,  and computed their commutators with $J_{12}$ as he all but dictates you do?

Not sure if my edition is different but I can't read there any mention about find two boosts, and commute with $J_{12}$. Why commuting with $J_{12}$ would show SO(3) mixes only $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_L$? Asking cause $J_{12}$ generate only SO(2)

I use $J_{12} =J_3$. See my answer. You know about equivalence transformations of Lie Algebras? I meant two boosts in lowest order of the rapidity ...

What Matt is trying to tell you in unfortunate complacent glib language, is that the momenta in the rest frame (8.71) and those of (8.68,9) are related by a boost
$$
B~(m,0,0,0)^T =\exp (-i \xi K_3) ~~(m,0,0,0)^T = (E,0,0,p)^T, \\
\xi \equiv \operatorname{arctanh} (p/E)~~.
$$
Consequently, the little group of $(m,0,0,0)^T $ generated by  $\vec J$ is mapped into that of  $(E,0,0,p)^T$ generated by the equivalent algebra $B^\dagger \vec J B$, with the same structure constants, so, then SO(3). You have thus mapped
(8.71) to (8.69).
Convince yourself that the three generators of this SO(3) little group scrambling (8.69) among themselves is generated by
$$  B^\dagger  J_3 B= J_3, \\
     B^\dagger  J_1 B, \qquad  B^\dagger  J_2 B ~.
$$
You may note $B^\dagger  J_1 B= J_1-\xi K_2+ O(\xi^2) $,
and the analog for $J_2$.

The way you explained is much more clear, and you didn’t spend more words then in the book. It seems like that to not mention the related and needed math he make it much more obscure

Thank you.... I have taught parts of that book and faced the frustrated indignation of students at his "you know, you know..." glibness...
